# Add days in datetime and convert to string format in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, datetime, webdriver, pycharm

I have a code requirement where the "expired date" should be +3 days of the current date in a string format. Following is my code,

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()  #Today's date is '2/11/2017'
expires_at = '%d/%d/%d' % (now.day + 3, now.month, now.year)
```

This works perfectly and output is similar to "5/11/2017" which is expected. However, this code breaks when the current date is 28th or 29th. Python somehow added the date to 33rd instead of skipping to 1st of the month. I have done my research and found a solution which works in Python Console (following) but failing to run under Selenium Web Driver and Pycharm.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> m = '29/10/2017'
>>> date = datetime.strptime(m, "%d/%m/%Y")
>>> modified_date = date + timedelta(days=3)
>>> datetime.strftime(modified_date, "%d/%m/%Y")
'01/11/2017'
```

When run the same code under pycharm, the following error occurs:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
   date = datetime.strptime(m, "%d/%m/%Y")
Exception: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'
```

Any help is appreciated. I am using python 3.6.1 if anyone's curious. Probably missing something very small (2 possible solutions but none of them works) but stuck on this code for 3 days and unable to find the correct solution.

Comment: I see a difference in the method name: strptime vs strftime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the previous poster, I have figured out I was dealing with a few issues 
1) I was adding both "from datetime import datetime, timedelta" and "import datetime" together. Removing one of them solved most of my issue. 
2) To get the current date using "from datetime import datetime", I did the following :

```
from datetime import datetime
now = "{:%Y_%m_%d}".format(datetime.now())
print(now)
```

The output I get is,

```
'2017_11_03'  #today's date
```

I only needed to specify 'datetime' once, i.e. "datetime.now()" as I was importing the class "datetime" from the "datetime" module.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you don't have the following in your code:

```
import datetime
```

If you do that , it will crash. Like:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import datetime
m = '29/10/2017'
date = datetime.strptime(m, "%d/%m/%Y")`


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I may have both the lines in my code. Need to double check.